# Django can't get user IP in AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load-Balanced Environment

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a load-balanced environment set up in AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a Django app deployed and running [Django-user-sessions](https://django-user-sessions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).  I'd like it to be able to log the user session external IP addresses, but everything that gets logged is an internal IP.  I have another environment that is not load-balanced and external user IPs are being collected, so I'm fairly sure the user IP is getting overwritten by the internal IP of the load balancer.

I have tried to install [django-xforwardedfor-middleware](https://github.com/allo-/django-xforwardedfor-middleware) which supposedly adds `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].split(',')[0].strip()` to each request, but this has not solved the problem.

I also have an HTTPS engine rewrite in my `.ebextensions` that is *not* running on the environment that is working properly, but I don't think it is the problem:

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
            <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
            </If>
```

Are there any other things I could try to get django-user-sessions to collect external user IPs?

Comment: Does the load balancer pass the user's ip address through? In which field? (look in request.META in your Django app)

Comment: Yes, I just check and it is actually contained in request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].  So it looks like the middleware isn't doing its job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: the positioning of `x_forwarded_for.middleware.XForwardedForMiddleware` matters.  It should come before `user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'x_forwarded_for.middleware.XForwardedForMiddleware',
    'user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  # the django-user-sessions middleware
    ...
]
```